# Why can't I directly pass a custom event args class into a method subscribing to my event?

Tags: c#, .net, events

Why can't I directly pass custom event arguments into a method subscribing to my event even though my custom event args class directly inherits from `EventArgs`?

For example, consider the two below classes. One is the class I want to work with, the other inherits from `EventArgs`, and contains some additional information related to the event:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public event EventHandler MyEvent;

        public void MyMethod(int myNumber)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myNumber);

            if(myNumber == 7)
            {
                MyEvent.Invoke(null, new MyCustomEvent() { Foo = "Bar" });
            }
        }
    }

    class MyCustomEvent : EventArgs
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So if a number 7 is passed into `MyMethod`, I want to invoke `MyEvent` passing in the a new instance of the `MyCustomEvent` class to any method subscribing to my event.

I subscribe to this from my main program like so:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            myClass.MyEvent += new EventHandler(myClass_MyEvent);

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                myClass.MyMethod(i);
            }
        }

        static void myClass_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Do Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Even though I am passing in a `MyCustomEvent` object when invoking the event, if I change the second parameter in the method subscribing to my event to a `MyCustomEvent` object I get a compile error. I need to instead explicitly cast the `EventArgs` object to a `MyCustomEvent` before I can access any additional fields/methods etc inside the class.

When working with an object that has a lot of different events, each one having a unique related custom `EventArgs` class, keeping track of what the EventArgs in each method subscribing to each event needs to be casted to can get a bit messy.

It would be a lot easier if I could pass my custom EventArgs class directly into the methods subscribing to my event.

Is this a possibility?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of declaring your event as being of type `EventHandler`, create a new delegate that specifically uses your custom event args class:

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs args);
public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
```

Now you can pass the arguments directly without casting.

The other option is to use the generic `EventHandler<T>`:

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent;
```

I prefer the former, since you can then give the delegate type a more descriptive name, though the latter is a bit quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your event using generic version of `EventHandler`:

```
public event EventHandler<MyCustomEvent> MyEvent;
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a default event handler just define your own that fits the signature you are trying to achieve...

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyCustomEventArgs e)
public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
```

Answer (score 1):

forgive me if i understood your question wrong.  I'm a little confused by not seeing any custom `EventArgs` class.

You can't make a method signature like

```
static void myClass_MyEvent(object sender, CustomEventArgs e)
```

for an event that expects a

```
static void myClass_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

That is backwards polymorphism, and polymorphism doesn't work backwards.

let's say your event accesses a `e.OnlyInCustomEventArgs`, but is instead passed the base object, `EventArgs`.  Then the contract has been broken.

Now what you can do is

```
static void myClass_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomEventArgs cea = (CustomEventArgs)e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code for a correctly implemented custom arg event handler.

```
class MyClass
{
    public event EventHandler<MyCustomEventArgs> MyEvent;

    public void MyMethod(int myNumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myNumber);

        if (myNumber == 7)
        {
            MyEvent.Invoke(null, new MyCustomEventArgs() { Foo = "Bar" });
        }
    }
}

class MyCustomEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.MyEvent += new EventHandler<MyCustomEventArgs>(myClass_MyEvent);

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            myClass.MyMethod(i);
        }
    }

    //This is the method signature that you need to use to handle the event
    static void myClass_MyEvent(object sender, MyCustomEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Foo); // prints "Bar"
        //Do Stuff
    }

    //If you need to handle more than one type of custom event args
    static void myClass_MyEvent<T>(object sender, T e) where T : EventArgs
    {
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```